# Declare a class inside another class' namespace without explicit nested declaration

Tags: c++, include, iterator, declaration

I'm implementing an iterator to a particular class, and the iterator needs access to `A` members, as well as `A` needs access to `iterator` -- I want to be able to declare `A::iterator it;`

I know I may simply nest a class inside the other, in this case, I would have:

```
class A {
public:
    class iterator {
    };
};
```

But both class `A` and `iterator` itself have a great load of code, and I would like to split these classes into two different files.

The problem here is that class `A` would naturally `#include iterator.hpp`, but `iterator` also needs to include `A`, in order to implement the proper iterator operators. And this is where I'm stuck at: even adding include guards I didn't manage to get this working.

---

Here's a snippet of what I have:

*a.hpp*:

```
# include iterator.hpp
# ifndef A_HPP
# define A_HPP

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    typedef iterator<T> iterator;
};
```

*iterator.hpp*:

```
# include a.hpp
# ifndef ITERATOR_HPP
# define ITERATOR_HPP

template <typename T>
class iterator {
public:
    // Constructor
    iterator(A<T> *a) {
    }
};
```

The classes are way bigger, that's why I didn't post the entire code

---

*Obs*: If it isn't possible to perform this recursive inclusion, but I could still manage to have the class `iterator` nested in the namespace of `A`, but declare outside class `A`, that would suffice.

Comment: Tried using typename A<T>?

Comment: You mean, instead of `typedef`?

Comment: This is a recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward declarations eliminate most of these problems. Note that you don't have to define member functions inside the class definition; you can define them later, when all the types have been defined. (If it helps, write on the blackboard 100 times: C++ is not Java).

```
class C;

class Iterator {
    // member function declarations
    // member data
};

class C {
    // member function declarations
    // member data
};

// member function definitions go here; there is
// no problem using C inside member
// functions of Iterator and vice versa
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much! Just as further reference, I've used: `template <typename T> class C { class iterator; };\n template <typename T> class C<T>::iterator {};` (:

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps make the class into a template argument of the iterator. Then the iterator won't need the immediate access to the class.

class:

```
#include "iterator.hpp"
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
  typedef Iterator<A, T> iterator;
};
```

iterator:

```
template <typename C, typename T>
class Iterator {
  Iterator (C* a);
}
```